# Find number of non-zero elements adjacent to zeros in numpy 2D array

Tags: python, numpy

Given a matrix, I want to count number of filled elements (non-zero cells) adjacent to empty (zero) cells, where adjacency is along rows (left/right).

I have tried playing around with `np.roll` and subtracting matrices, but I'm not sure how to code this without loops.

For example, given the matrix:

```
arr = 
[[1 1 0 0 0 0 0 0 1 0]
 [1 1 0 0 0 0 0 1 1 1]
 [0 1 1 0 0 0 0 0 0 0]
 [0 1 1 0 0 0 0 0 0 0]
 [0 1 1 0 0 0 0 0 0 0]
 [0 0 1 0 0 0 0 0 0 0]
 [0 0 1 0 0 0 0 0 0 0]
 [0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0]
 [0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0]]
```

We have 12 non-zero elements adjacent to zeros.

Comment: Do your matrix always contain solely `0`s and `1`s?

Comment: It didn't originally, I used masks to convert it, to simplify the problem.

Comment: I can count more than 12: 3 in the first row, 2 in the second row, 2 in the third, 2 in the fourth, 2 in the fifth, 2 in the sixth and 2 in the seventh.... Total 15

Comment: @Bazingaa , I think you're referring to the number of zeros, not to the number of ones.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

**Approach #1**

We can use [`2D convolution`](https://docs.scipy.org/doc/scipy/reference/generated/scipy.signal.convolve2d.html) to solve it with an appropriate kernel `([1,1,1])` or `([1,0,1])` on the `zeros` mask and look for the convolution summations to be `>=1`, which signals at least one zero in each sliding window of three elements and with an additional check of the current element being non-zero confirms that there's at least one neighboring `0`.

The implementation would look something like this -

```
In [245]: a  # input array
Out[245]: 
array([[1, 1, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 1, 0],
       [1, 1, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 1, 1, 1],
       [0, 1, 1, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0],
       [0, 1, 1, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0],
       [0, 1, 1, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0],
       [0, 0, 1, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0],
       [0, 0, 1, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0],
       [0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0],
       [0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0]])

In [246]: from scipy.signal import convolve2d

In [248]: k = [[1,1,1]] # kernel for convolution

In [249]: ((convolve2d(a==0,k,'same')>=1) & (a!=0)).sum()
Out[249]: 12
```

**Approach #2**

Another approach would be making use of `slicing` as we would look for one-off offsetted elements along each row for the zeros and non-zeros matches for the left and right hand sides `LHS` and `RHS` and finally sum those -

```
maskRHS = (a[:,1:]==0) & (a[:,:-1]!=0)
maskLHS = (a[:,1:]!=0) & (a[:,:-1]==0)
maskRHS[:,1:] |= maskLHS[:,:-1]
out = maskRHS.sum() + maskLHS[:,-1].sum()
```

Comment: The first solution looks okay, but the second won't properly take edge cases into account. If you change the bottom right 0 into a 1, you'll get a 12 where you should be getting a 13.

Comment: @fuglede Good catch, thanks! Needed to add sum of last col of `maskLHS` there.

Comment: Oh wow that's comprehensive, thanks! Could you please provide some more intuition about  why/how those specific filters ([1,1,1] or [1,0,1]) work for this?

Answer (score 3):

You should be able to do something like

```
ar = a[:,1:] & ~a[:,:-1]
al = a[:,:-1] & ~a[:,1:]
al[:, 0].sum() + (al[:, 1:] | ar[:, :-1]).sum() + ar[:, -1].sum()  # 12
```

Here, the idea is that `ar` keeps track of those 1s that are to the right of a 0, while `al` keeps track of those 1s that are to the left of a 0, and we then take care not to double count.

If you don't mind working with the transpose instead, the entire thing becomes a bit more concise:

```
b = a.T
br = b[1:] & ~b[:-1]
bl = b[:-1] & ~b[1:]
bl[0].sum() + (bl[1:] | br[:-1]).sum() + br[-1].sum()  # Also 12
```

A perhaps more readable version that avoids having to handle the two edges separately would be to extend both of `b[1:]` and `b[:-1]` with a column of ones:

```
edge = np.ones(9, int)
(b & ~(np.vstack([b[1:], edge]) & np.vstack([edge, b[:-1]]))).sum()  # Also 12
```